# R: cannot allocate vector of size 10.4 Gb

Tags: r, memory

Hi i am working with R package consensusclusterplus.
And I got this error.

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.4 Gb

This is what I tried from the previous posts. But could not resolve. Can someone please help. Thanks. I have only one object in my work space.

> memory.limit()

[1] 16062

> memory.limit(size=112000)

[1] 112000

> tresults = ConsensusClusterPlus(td, maxK=4, reps=100, pItem=0.8, pFeature=1, title=title, clusterAlg="km",distance="euclidean",seed=1262118388.71279,plot=NULL)
>   Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.4 Gb

Comment: To confirm, you have enough ram on your machine to handle this, correct?

Comment: I thought I can use the second command to expand the memory.But that also didn't work. Any ways I just need 10GB. But my laptop has 16GB ram and this is still not working.

Comment: You better run your data on the cloud. AWS is a good option.